# Display Parameter in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When a user runs the report, they can select a multi-value parameter. I know I can use Parameters!*Value*.Label(0), Parameters!*Value*.Label(1), etc to display the each of the values based on their location within the array, but the number of the values changes based on how many values the user selects.

The report separates each value onto a separate page. I'm looking to (a) have an expression that identifies which value's info is displayed on the page, and (b) an expression that labels the tab as the value when the report is exported to Excel. I expect the same expression would work for both.

I believe I should be using *Array.IndexOf(Split(Parameters!Value.Label.ToString(), ","), Parameters!Client.Label)*, but just get *#Error* as the output when the report renders. I'm not sure, but it seems like the Array... expression would only identify the location within the array.

Could someone offer some insight into where the syntax is wrong? I'm not sure if the issue is syntax or it's an issue of how to specify which dataset to use in the expression.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should use

```
=Join(Parameters!CSR.Label, ", ")
```

Comment: This would create an array of the parameters. I'm looking to identity each parameter that makes up the array. For example; if the user selects "A", "B", and "C" as the multiple-value parameters, the first page would display A, the second page would display "B", and the third page would display "C".

Comment: if the parameters are linked directly to the data (e.g. selecting from a list of countries so the report is filtered on those countries), then you could group the report by the related column and use that in the group header and add a page break at that group level. This way you don't need any expressions to extract info from your selected parameters.